# hide a header of a column with binding data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

would it be possible to do it like this?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Export" Visible='<%# Bind("isExported") %>'>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried it and I got this problem:

```
The TemplateField control with a two-way databinding to field deviceExport must have an ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<%# Eval("isExported")%>` instead of `<%# Bind("isExported")%>`